# How does DefaultValueAttriubte work for Encoding?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I've a property decorated with `DefaultValueAttribute`.

The code looks like this:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Encoding), "utf-8")]
public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
```

There's a Reset-Method that restores all default values of all properties:

```
public void Reset()
{
    foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ILoggedChannelValueFileExportInfo)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
    {
        property.ResetValue(this);
    }
}
```

This works perfect for all standard properties including a property with ReturnType `CultureInfo`.
I tried to specify `utf-8`, `utf8` and both in upper case but nothing works.

What do I have to specify to make it work?

I'm able to do this via reflection but I hope that there's a way to use the `TypeDescriptor`.

EDIT:
Due to answer of Hans Passant I wrote a `TypeConverter`. That's the whole code:

```
public class Foo
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EncodingTypeConverter))]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Encoding), "UTF-8")]
    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }

    public void Reset()
    {
        foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
        {
            property.ResetValue(this);
        }
    }
}

public class EncodingTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return value is string ? Encoding.GetEncoding((string)value) : base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) ? value.ToString() : base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

After creating an instance and call `Reset` Encoding is still null and no method is called from `EncodingTypeConverter`. What should I do?`

There is no UI involved - no property grid. The only thing is the TypeDescriptor that should reset the value.

EDIT:
It is nearly impossible to write my own `TypeConverter`-call because the `DefaultValueAttribute` doesn't store the specified string value. It hurts. Here's my implementation that doesn't work. Maybe there's someone who can use it to create a solution:

```
public virtual void ResetValues()
{
    foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TAttributedType)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
    {
        if (property.CanResetValue(this))
        {
            property.ResetValue(this);
            continue;
        }

        var defaultValueAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
        var typeConverterAttribute = (TypeConverterAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(TypeConverterAttribute)];
        if (defaultValueAttribute == null || !(defaultValueAttribute.Value is string) ||
            typeConverterAttribute == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeConverterAttribute.ConverterTypeName))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var typeConverterType = Type.GetType(typeConverterAttribute.ConverterTypeName);
        if (typeConverterType == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var typeConverter = (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeConverterType);
        if (typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            var propertyValue = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(defaultValueAttribute.Value);
            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, propertyValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no type converter for the Encoding class, you'll have to write one and tell the designer about it with the [TypeConverter] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `TypeConverterAttribute` and defining a `DefaultValue(typeof(Encoding), "UTF-8")` will not work. The constructor for `DefaultValue` tries to find a `TypeConverter` from the `TypeDescriptor` that doesn't use the `TypeConverterAttribute`.

Here is an implementation of the `ResetValues`-method that uses a string-value in `DefaultValueAttribute`and the `TypeConverterAttribute` to load a default value.

```
public virtual void ResetValues()
{
    foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TAttributedType)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
    {
        var defaultValueAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
        var typeConverterAttribute = (TypeConverterAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(TypeConverterAttribute)];
        if (defaultValueAttribute != null && defaultValueAttribute.Value is string &&
            typeConverterAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeConverterAttribute.ConverterTypeName))
        {
            var typeConverterType = Type.GetType(typeConverterAttribute.ConverterTypeName);
            if (typeConverterType != null)
            {
                var typeConverter = (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeConverterType);
                if (typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
                {
                    var propertyValue = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(defaultValueAttribute.Value);
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(this, propertyValue);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (property.CanResetValue(this))
        {
            property.ResetValue(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The used `TypeConverter` is:

```
public class EncodingTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return value is string ? Encoding.GetEncoding((string)value) : base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

And the attibuted property is:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EncodingTypeConverter))]
[DefaultValue("UTF-8")]
public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }
```

Note that the `ResetValues`-method first tests for a `TypeConverter` and a specified `DefaultValue`. That's needed because the `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` returns `true` if a string is specified as default value. This is not convertable to Encoding.